# How to deploy a war file in jboss using maven pom.xml?

Tags: maven, jboss, pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tripod.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Karthik-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Karthik-project Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <jboss-as.deploy.hostname>localhost</jboss-as.deploy.hostname>  <!-- Where to deploy. -->
        <jboss-as.deploy.user>admin</jboss-as.deploy.user>
        <jboss-as.deploy.pass>admin</jboss-as.deploy.pass>
        <plugin.war.warName>target/Karthik-project.war</plugin.war.warName>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                    <warName>target/Karthik-project.war</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.3.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>admin</password>
                    <jbossHome>/home/smadugula/jboss-eas-5.2</jbossHome>
                    <serverName>Standalone</serverName>
                    <targetDir>target</targetDir>
                    <fileName>target/Karthik-project.war</fileName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have referred to various examples on stackoverflow and other links on google and I created this file. When I use mvn jboss:deploy , although I get a Build-Success message I get a message like : 
    [INFO] No files configured to deploy/undeploy.
How to do I configure the war file ? Can anybody Help me with this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: try using the maven cargo plugin.

Comment: do you use jboss in standalone or domain mode?

Answer (score 1):

I maybe wrong, but the maven-war-plugin is primarily used to package your application into a war file.

You should try to use the [maven-cargo-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) because it provides a lot of control for deployments, starting and stopping containers.

Here is a sample [Deploying to a local container](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deploying+to+a+running+container) configuration.

Answer (score -1):

It looks you didn't [read the documentation of the plugin](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/7.4.Final/examples/deployment-example.html) cause the deployment looks like this:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           ...
                        </configuration>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
        ...
    </build>
...
</project>
```

If you don't use the `phase` tag the execution of the plugin is bound to `package` phase. So you have to call `mvn package`.

Comment: Actually I read it but I was instructed not to use the execution tags so I tried to execute pom without it. I executed the pom using mvn jboss:deploy

Comment: Who instructed you you not to use the execution tags? And why? You can omit the execution tags which means the plugin is bound to it's default life-cycle phases.